# Is hbase create table is lightweight?

Tags: hbase

I'm want redesign a exist table which is contains two columns `uuid` and  `consumerId`. In this stage, distinct uuid has 50 amounts and consumerId for every uuid more then 100k.
So, is it reasonable create 50 tables and named with uuid, such as `consumerId_{uuid001}` to avoid redundancy caused by `uuid` column?

Comment: which database you are currently using?

Comment: @RohitVerma, Mysql but I can switch to others.For the stage, is there a database will caused a different result?

Comment: why did you tag your question with hbase then?

Comment: Sorry for my slight reply. I have point using hbase in my question and I consider other database maybe relative because you ask me my database again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to think of use cases of how you going to use this database. 
Do you need to find each all `uuid`s for specific `consumerId`?
With design that you propose it means that you’ll need to query 50 different tables and then unite results which is not an easy task at all.

I would go with one of the following options:

1. leave as is - it’s the most flexible way you’ll be able to query all `uuid`s by `consumerId` and vice verse quite easily. I don’t see a problem of having extra 100k integers it’s just couple kilobytes.
2. Modify structure so `consumerId`s are stored in a list for each `uuid`. Pseudocode: `table(uuid: String, consumerId: List<String>)` This will definitely be compact representation, but you might struggle build some type of queries (where `consumerId` is one of parameters).

Comment: uuid is java UUID to string, it has 36 char. 36 * 2 * 100,000 / 1024 / 1024 = 6M. Is it doesn't matter?

Comment: Well, still modern database operate with terabytes and petabytes. 6M does not sound like a serious load.